# How can I sort numbers of output like using way of %2d in printf(), when I use cout?

Tags: c++, printf, cout

How can I sort numbers of output, similar to using  `%2d` in `printf()`, when I use `cout` ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into `setw`. This will set the output width just like %2.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw